# Setting up Google Pay to send users money

Tags: android, payment-processing, android-developer-api, google-pay

I want to set up my Android app to accept money from users Google Pay accounts and disperse money to Google Pay accounts all from the app. I have seen people mention that Google Pay returns a token, and I need to use a payment processor, however I am not sending the money to their bank accounts. I want the entire transaction to go from their Google Pay account, to my Google Pay account, back to their Google Pay account. Is that possible or does Google Pay simply return an instance of their banking information even when they're using Google Pay as well?

Comment: you can integrate google pay with paypal and than send money to users through paypal

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Google Pay API does not offer this functionality. It's used by merchants to accept payments from their customers and it thus requires a payment processor.

[Google Pay Send](https://support.google.com/pay/send/answer/7523247) is a feature inside of Google Pay which is used for peer-to-peer payments and it doesn't offer an API.

In short, you can't leverage Google Pay for third party money transfers directly - you would need to use a payment processor or gateway to facilitate the transfers.

Comment: Hey can you clarify what you mean by "payment processor" and "gateway"? I simply have a google pay or paypal or bank etc account and I want to send the funds to a user via API. I understand there is no API for that but what's the payment processor / gateway workaround? Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: What you're describing is Google Pay Send, which is a different product used for P2P money transfers (usually between family or friends). If you're a business (merchant) charging for goods and services, you need to have a payment processor or gateway (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_gateway).

Comment: Hello, @fstanis! Thanks for your answer. So the point is we as a service send money to the end-user. We do not charge them anything, instead, we send them funds. Is it accomplishable to send funds to their google pay account?